# from scapy.all import * FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]

Tags: importerror, scapy

I have installed the scapy module in Python3 on Windows 8.1 by using the command `pip3 install scapy-python3`, and I can load the scapy module successfully.

But when i use the command `from scapy.all import * error`, it gives a error:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system can not find the file specified.

I really don't know how to deal with it. The flowing below is the specific about the accident:

[image]

Comment: can you confirm that you are running python3 to run your script, not just python (which may not recognise pip3 modules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your bug with the latest development version.

Upgrading Scapy to the current development version from the [official repository](https://github.com/secdev/scapy) should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your time and your anwers, i works now.

Comment: Thanks but you should avoid letting such comments. Comments are for helping build or fix a solution (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757). Up-votes (and down-votes) are to be used to show that you appreciate a question (or an answer).